# Mat doesn't work with bitmap in Android OpenCV

Tags: android, opencv, bitmap, mat

I'm trying to implement some filters in a Bitmap with OpenCV in Android, the first step is detect a face and split in 2 images (eyes).
But when I try implement a Mat function to do some Image processing it die.

The error text is this:

08-05 17:54:58.659: E/AndroidRuntime(11005): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: n_Mat

And the code is this, I'm getting crazy with OpenCV.

```
package org.opencv.samples.puzzle15;

import org.opencv.android.BaseLoaderCallback;
import org.opencv.android.LoaderCallbackInterface;
import org.opencv.android.Utils;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;
import android.media.FaceDetector;
import android.media.FaceDetector.Face;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class Puzzle15Activity extends Activity {

    private static final String  TAG = "Sample::TestFilter::Activity";


    private ImageView face;
    private ImageView leftEyeImg;
    private ImageView rightEyeImg;

    private Bitmap fL;
    private Bitmap fR;


     FaceDetector fD;
     FaceDetector.Face[] faceArray;
     Bitmap rightEye;
     Bitmap leftEye;
     int y;

    private int                  mGameWidth;
    private int                  mGameHeight;



    private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {

        @Override
        public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
            switch (status) {
                case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
                {
                    Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");
                    //starEverything();
                } break;
                default:
                {
                    super.onManagerConnected(status);
                } break;
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        Log.i(TAG, "Ejecutando onCreate");

        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        face = new ImageView(this);
        face.setImageResource(R.drawable.asd);
        leftEyeImg = new ImageView(this);
        rightEyeImg = new ImageView(this);

        int max = 5;
        BitmapFactory.Options bfo = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bfo.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
        bfo.inScaled = false;
        bfo.inDither = false;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.face1, bfo);
        int w = bitmap.getWidth();
        int h = bitmap.getHeight();
        FaceDetector fd = new FaceDetector(w, h, max);
        Face[] faces = new Face[max];
        int c = fd.findFaces(bitmap, faces);
        Log.d("TAG", "FACES: "+c);
        for (int i=0;i<c;i++) {
            Log.d("TAG", Float.toString(faces[i].eyesDistance()));
        }

        PointF fpx;
        fpx = new PointF();

        faces[0].getMidPoint(fpx);

        float fds = faces[0].eyesDistance();

        Log.d("TAG", "x: "+fpx.x);
        Log.d("TAG", "y: "+fpx.y);
        Log.d("TAG", "fsd: "+fds);

        Log.d("TAG", "w: "+w);
        Log.d("TAG", "h: "+h);
        fL =cropBitmap1(bitmap,fpx.x, fpx.y, fds, fds);
        fR =cropBitmap1(bitmap, fpx.x-fpx.y/2, fpx.y, fds, fds);

        rightEyeImg.setImageBitmap(fR);
        leftEyeImg.setImageBitmap(fL);

        layout.addView(leftEyeImg);
        layout.addView(rightEyeImg);

        setContentView(layout);

        someFilter(fL);
    }

    public void someFilter(Bitmap a){
        synchronized (this){
            Mat tmp = new Mat (a.getWidth(), a.getHeight(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
            Utils.bitmapToMat(a, tmp);
            Imgproc.cvtColor(tmp, tmp, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);

            Imgproc.cvtColor(tmp, tmp, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2RGB, 4);
            Utils.matToBitmap(tmp, a);
        }

    }
    private Bitmap cropBitmap1(Bitmap source, Float x, Float y, Float h, Float w)
    {
        Bitmap cropped = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, Math.round(x),Math.round(y)-Math.round(h)/4, Math.round(h), Math.round(h)/2);
        return cropped;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check if any faces detected before lines

```
faces[0].getMidPoint(fpx);
float fds = faces[0].eyesDistance();
```

Second thind I've noticed is
     Mat tmp = new Mat (a.getWidth(), a.getHeight(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
You should change rows and cols for matrix:

```
Mat tmp = new Mat (a.getHeight(),a.getWidth(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
```

Comment: Thank you, well I resolved the problem with a Callback to charge OpenCV Library again after do the face recognition function and it works perfectly.